# False oath on Allah

Tags: halal-haram, allah, oaths

I was in an argument with my sister because I was going to clean our fan with water by turning it off and she told my mother that I was going to clean it without turning it off  so I swore an oath of allah that I was not going to do it my intention was to say i was not going to do it without turning it off which is the truth but I don't remember if i said that I was going to do it with the fan off so does that count for a false oath if so does Allah forgive false oath on his name

Answer (score 0):

Allah will not punish you for whatever you say unintentionally and your intention was not to give false oath, Allah says in the Quran; (Allah does not impose blame upon you for what is unintentional in your  oaths, but he imposes blame upon you for what your hearts have earned. Allah is forgiving and forbearing.)(2:225)